# PHP Laravel : How to track client Device or Browser in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I'm building a laravel application where I want to track the device which he used for last view in that webpage. for that I have used `antonioribeiro/tracker` package. But I couldn't track the device with package. Is there any other way to find it out. Or can any one help me to get the problem with the controller.

I am getting following Error while I run the program:

> ErrorException in DepartmentController.php line 28: Trying to get
>   property of non-object

And here is the controller:

```
 public function postdepartmentSave(Request $request)
    {
         $this->validate($request,[
            'code' => 'required|min:2|max:7|unique:departments',          
            'name' => 'required|unique:departments',          
            ]);
            $department = new Department();           
            $department->code = $request->Input(['code']);            
            $department->name = $request->Input(['name']);
            $visitor = Tracker::currentSession();
        var_dump( $visitor->device->platform ); // <-- Where the error is (line 28)

            $department->save();            
            return redirect('departmentSavePage');          
    }
```

Comment: which line is line 28?

Comment: can u post department controller..

Comment: @ItaiBar-Haim Line 28:    `var_dump( $visitor->device->platform );`

Comment: try adding `var_dump( $visitor->device );` just before that line. I suspect the member `device` is uninitialized and that's why you can't access the member `platform`.

Comment: I have tried that  too, nothing got actually!